# Confusion on the connection between causality and stationarity and possible implications

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, estimation, expected-value, stationarity

Let $(x_{t})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ be a causal AR(p) process with operator $\phi$ such that $\phi(L)=\phi_{0}-\phi_{1}L-...-\phi_{p}L^{p}$ and $(\epsilon_{t})_{t \in \mathbb N_{0}}$ white noise sequence:

By definition, there exists a sequence $(\psi_{t})_{t \in \mathbb N_{0}}$ such that $x_{t}=\psi(L)\epsilon_{t}$ where $\psi(L)=\psi_{0}+\psi_{1}L+\psi_{2}L^{2}+...$ with the Lag operator $L$ and $\sum\limits_{j\in \mathbb N_{0}}\lvert \psi_{j}\rvert<\infty$.

One equivalent property of causality is that all roots of $\phi$ lie outside the unit circle.

Furthermore, introducing the notion of weak stationarity, meaning mean stationarity and covariance stationarity of the time series $x_{t}$. We get that a AR(p) process $x_{t}$ is stationary, if the roots of $\phi$ lie outside of the unit circle.

So by the above thoughts I have espoused, I may assume the following:

causality $\implies$ stationarity with mean $0$.

This leads me to what I think may be a contradiction, because under the assumption that $x_{t}$ is stationary, we have

$\mathbb E[x_{t}]=\frac{\phi_{0}}{1-\phi_{1}-...-\phi_{p}}$

So even if i did assume causality, this would have to mean that

$0=\mathbb E[x_{t}]=\frac{\phi_{0}}{1-\phi_{1}-...-\phi_{p}}$, which is certainly not true, and would only be true if I assume $\phi_{0}=0$.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: "...a stationary AR(p) process $x_{t}$ is stationary, if the roots of $\phi$ lie outside of the unit circle..." is a somewhat sloppy statement. The AR(p) model has a stationary solution if and only if $\phi$ has no roots on the unit circle.
A special case is when all roots of $\phi$ lie outside the unit circle, in which case the stationary solution is also causal. When all roots of $\phi$ lie inside the unit circle, the model has stationary non-causal solution.

Comment: @Michael OP is talking causality and outside unit circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Causality is by definition a special case of stationarity. Stationarity, or causality, does not imply mean 0.

Where you went wrong is you're comparing different AR models---one without intercept and one with. Stationary AR models without intercept have zero mean in general, whether causal or non-causal. Vice versa for those with intercept.

When you defined $x_t$ by $\phi(L) x_t = \epsilon_t$, e.g.
$$
(\phi_0 - \phi_1 L)x_t = \epsilon_t, \quad (*)
$$ 
you defined an AR model with no intercept. Such processes necessarily have mean zero. (As you already pointed out, in the stationary case where there is a MA representation, it's a (infinite) sum of mean-zero variables.) $\phi_0$ is customarily taken to be 1 in such formulations.

On the other hand, the expression for the unconditional mean
$$
\mathbb E[x_{t}] = \frac{\phi_{0}}{1-\phi_{1}}
$$
is for the causal AR model with intercept
$$
x_{t+1} = \phi_0 + \phi_1 x_t + \epsilon_t. \quad (**)
$$
This is *not* the same model as $(*)$.

Instead, the lag operator formulation of $(**)$ is
$$
(1 - \phi_1 L) x_t = \phi_0 + \epsilon_t.
$$
So in the causal case 
$$
x_t = \frac{\phi_0}{1-\phi_1} + \underbrace{ \psi(L)\epsilon_{t}}_\text{$\sum_{h \geq 0} \psi_h \epsilon_{t-h}$}, \;\; \psi_h = \phi_1^h,
$$
which has mean 
$$
\mathbb E[x_{t}] = \frac{\phi_{0}}{1-\phi_{1}}.
$$

Comment: That helps a lot! This leads me to the question, can a process with a 'constant' or 'drift' of the form, e.g. $x_{t}=\phi_{0}+\phi_{1}x_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}$ still be causal?

Comment: @MinaThuma, yes, when $|\phi_1|<1$

Comment: @Aksakal But what would my representation of $x_{t}=\sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb N_{0}}\psi_{j}\epsilon_{t-j}$ look like to account for the constant?

Comment: @MinaThuma, obviously, not, because mean of the right hand size is clearly zero, while of the left side it's not

Comment: But that's the definition of causality...

Comment: @MinaThuma "But that's the definition of causality... "---no, a causal MA process is just an example of causal process with zero mean. The general definition of causality is that roots of the AR polynomial lies outside unit circle. The definition does not say anything about the drift term.

Comment: Michael or Aksakal: Do either of you know of a good reference for this material. By "this material" I mean relations between causaiity-stationarity etc. I have a lot of time series books but I could be missing something good. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton My guess is probably all the reference you have for time series from a statistical perspective would cover this. Econometric texts sometimes skip some details in this aspect (maybe engineering too? I don't know).

Comment: @Michael: Most of the ones I have do a good job on stationarity but no so much causality. I'll look again because I could have missed something since I don't think I've ever read any of them from first page to last. Do you have any statistical favorites ? I'm just curious because you ( and Aksakal ) really know your stuff so I'm thinking I should get and read atleast parts of the ones you have. Thanks. And I hope you don't say "Box-Jenkins et al". :).

Comment: @mlofton Brockwell and Davis might be good suggestions; there are two, pitched at somewhat different levels with different focus (if you don't have them already).

Comment: Hi Michael: : I have both and have always intended to read the yellow one from beginning to end. I just haven't gotten around to it. Definitely it looks like a rigorous-usefui book at a glance. thanks.